# A JSON parsing error has occurred: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct

Tags: python

[image]I'm wanting to do a put in an API where I will receive data from an excel spreadsheet.
Here's my python code:

```
for s, Id in enumerate(spreed_sheet["itemId"]):   
  mark = str(spreed_sheet.loc[s,"markup"])
  prod_price = str(float(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "listPrice"]))
  prod_base = str(float(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "basePrice"]))
  prod_cost = str(int(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "costPrice"])) 
  policy_produ = str(int(spreed_sheet.loc[s,"tradePolicyId"]))
  prod_value = str(float(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "value"]))
  fixed_list = str(int(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "listPrice"]))
  min_qt = str(int(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "minQuantity"])) 
  date_from = str(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "from"]) 
  date_to = str(spreed_sheet.loc[s, "to"])
 
  payloads = {"itemId": Id, "markup": mark, "listPrice": prod_price, "basePrice": prod_base, "costPrice": prod_cost, "tradePolicyId": policy_produ, "value": prod_value, "listPrice": fixed_list, "minQuantity": min_qt, "from": date_from, "to": date_to}
  url = f"https://myapi/myaccountname/pricing/prices/{Id}"

  response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=payloads)   
  print(response.text)
  response = response.json()
```

I change the name of account name for "myaccountname", in my code the name is there. But, when I try to pass the excel file for the api I get the follow error:

```
[Errno Expecting value] A JSON parsing error has occurred: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field PutPriceRequest.itemId of type string : 0
```

The API call actually has two listPrice. The response body would look like this:

```
{
    "markup": 30,
    "basePrice": 100,
    "listPrice": 12,
    "costPrice": 40,  
    "fixedPrices": [
        {
            "tradePolicyId": "1",
            "value": 2.99,
            "listPrice": 1,
            "minQuantity": 1,
            "dateRange": {
                "from": "2020-05-21T22:00:00Z",
                "to": "2020-05-28T22:00:00Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "tradePolicyId": "1",
            "value": 0.49,
            "listPrice": null,
            "minQuantity": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

### Edit after making the changes

payloads = {"markup": mark, "listPrice": prod_price, "basePrice": prod_base, "costPrice": prod_cost, "tradePolicyId": policy_produ, "value": prod_value, "listPrice": fixed_list, "minQuantity": min_qt, "from": date_from, "to": date_to}

Comment: It sounds like you're making an invalid request to the API. Where is the documentation that tells you how to structure your requests?

Comment: Put the *full error message including the stack trace*

Answer (score -1):

The error message is telling you that the type of value received for `itemId` is not correct.

You've called the API with a number as the `itemId` field, but the API is expecting a string.

So you could modify that part of the code to:

```py
payloads = {"itemId": str(Id), ...
```

You should look at the API specification to see what types are being expected for the payload items. You're converting all of the other data items to a string, but it's unlikely that the API is expecting everything to be strings.

Comment: Ah! Ok! It really isn't all strings. I don't need to modify it inside the for but inside the payloads, as you did above!??

Comment: No, the error message from the API just states that the itemId needs to be a string and you're currently passing in an int. So just need to modify the itemId value to get past that error.

Comment: I changed the specific types expected in the API. And I got this error: The request is invalid: Item 2 must have exactly two values filled between basePrice, costPrice and markup. This is the api: https://developers.vtex.com/vtex-rest-api/reference/createupdatepriceorfixedprice

Comment: For that API you should not be including `itemId` in the payload. Instead the itemId is in the URL. It should not be in the PUT request. In order to fix the new error you'll have to add the complete payload you're sending so we can figure out why the API is not working for you.

Comment: So I put the itemId because there is an itemId in both the API and the url. In the url I left it that way because I want it to get the id inside the api and pass it to each one, so that each one is registered at a different price. My payloads is what is in the code: payloads = {"itemId": str(Id), "markup": mark, "listPrice": prod_price, "basePrice": prod_base, "costPrice": prod_cost, "tradePolicyId": policy_produ, "value": prod_value, "listPrice": fixed_list, "minQuantity": min_qt, "from": date_from, "to": date_to}

Comment: itemId is not part of the payload specification for that API, it is a path parameter. Don't put it in the payload.

Comment: I edited my question by sending a photo of my spreadsheet. Because within the API there is a requirement to send this itemId: itemId
integer
required
SKU unique identifier number

Comment: Yes, and the ItemId is in the URL - you do not need to add it to the payload, it is extracted by the API from the URL path. As per the API docs.

Comment: I did that and still got the error: The request is invalid: Item 2 must have exactly two values filled between basePrice, costPrice and markup

Comment: Sure, so now you have a new problem to solve. In order to do that we need to know exactly what payload you're sending to the API. Add it to the question with an edit or start a new question. :)

Comment: Sure. I edited the question with the payloads